# New django template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-cms

I am trying to edit some things in django and am running into a few problems as I am quite new to it.

I am working off an existing django configuration with templates that currently work, but I don't really understand how to create new templates. If I create a new .html file in my templates folder in "myprojects" and then declare the new template under cms_templates = (...) in settings.py nothing happens. Am I missing a step to get the template to upload and appear in my cms?

I also had a problem with an existing template, when I try to go to the contact page I am told that the template does not exist: http://paul.evansoderberg.com/en/contact/
The template is declared under "cms_templates", the file exists in the templates folder, and the page is created in django cms yet I get this error message.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

In settings I have :

```
CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('index.html', 'index'),
    ('contact.html', 'contact'),
    ('main.html', 'main'),
    ('about.html', 'about'),
    ('cv.html', 'cv'),
)
```

The template field in admin is set to "contact"

Comment: Please post your CMS_TEMPLATES setting, also what's the value of the template field when you edit the /contact/ page in admin ?

Comment: I have added the information in my original post, although I have now figured out that when clicking on contact the browser was trying to send me to a page called name.html, which didn't exist. I created a new file called name.html in my templates folder and now, with the template field in admin set to contact, the browser loads name.html but displays the contents of contact.html. So now I'm wondering why it goes through this name.html file first.

Comment: There's no way the CMS loads this name.html if it's not in your CMS_TEMPLATES setting. The only way is if the contact.html file extends or loads this name.html